# How to add a class to term

Tags: taxonomy

Good day,
i am try to add an active class after i choose the alphabet but it's cannot working

```
        <?php
        $alp_list = get_terms(array( 'taxonomy' => 'alphabets','orderby' => 'name', 'hide_empty' => false ) );

        foreach ( $alp_list as $alp ) {
            echo '<a href="';
            bloginfo('url');
            echo '/?s='.$alp->slug;
            echo '&section=member_list';
            echo '&alp='.$alp->slug;
            echo '&submit=search">'.$alp->name.'</a>'."\n";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for; first get the query string for `alp` and make a conditional statement every item in the loop against the query string `alp`

```
$selected_slug = $_GET['alp'] ? $_GET['alp'] : '';
$alp_class = '';

$alp_list = get_terms(array( 'taxonomy' => 'alphabets','orderby' => 'name', 'hide_empty' => false ) );

foreach ( $alp_list as $alp ) {
    if($selected_slug === $alp->slug) $alp_class = 'active';

    printf('<a href="%1$s/?s=%2$s&section=member_list&alp=%2$s&submit=search" class="%3$s">%4$s</a><br/>', get_bloginfo('url'), $alp->slug, $alp_class, $alp->name);
}
```

**Updated** code to add the `active` class on the link.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: its working but i just want to add the class on the selected aphlabet.
it is possible to do?

Comment: @JsLaw forgot to add the conditional logic to determine if the class should be added. My fault :)